# A PHP MySQL Error which I just cannot work out

Tags: php, mysql

I'm playing with PHP/MySQL and trying to teach myself online, but can't figure this out for the life of me.

I have been following a PHP tutorial at http://www.keithjbrown.co.uk/vworks/php/php_p5.php

This page is at tasmanianracing.com/horses.php

I'm getting the following mysql error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'WHERE
>   (horses.horseID = )' at line 1

which is being thrown up from my function update_horse()

My code is below - if someone could help me out I'd be forever grateful!

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Horses | Horse Database</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php

if (!$_REQUEST['Submit']) {
 html_form();
} elseif ($_REQUEST['Submit'] == "View Horse") {
 select_horse();
} elseif ($_REQUEST['Submit'] == "Edit") {
 get_data();
} elseif ($_REQUEST['Submit'] == "Update") {
 update_horse();
}

function my_conn() {

/* sets the variables for MySQL connection */

$server = "***"; // this is the server address and port
$username = "***"; // this is the mysql username
$password = "***"; // this is the mysql password

/* connects to the MySQL server */

$link = @mysql_connect ($server, $username, $password)
or die (mysql_error());

/* defines the active database for the connection */

if (!@mysql_select_db("tashorse_tasform", $link)) {

 echo "<p>There has been an error.  This is the error message:</p>";
 echo "<p><strong>" . mysql_error() . "</strong></p>";
 echo "Please contact your systems administrator with the details";

}

return $link;

}

function html_form() {

?>

<p>Please enter the search term for the horse</p>

<form name="horsesearch" method="post" action="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
Name of horse: <input type="text" name="horse_name">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="View Horse" />
</form>

<?

}

function select_horse() {
?>
<h4>Horse Search</h4>
<?

$conn = my_conn();

/* Sets the SQL Query */

$sql = "SELECT * FROM horses";
$sql .= " WHERE (horses.horse_name = '{$_POST['horse_name']}')";

/* Passes a Query to the Active Database */

$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
if (!$result) {
 echo("<p>Error performing query: " . mysql_error() . "</p>");
 exit();
}

/* starts the table and creates headings */

?>

<table>
<tr>
<td><strong>Horse Name</strong></td>
<td><strong>Year Foaled</strong></td>
<td><strong>Trainer</strong></td>
<td><strong>Owners</strong></td>
<td><strong>Silks</strong></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<?
/* retrieves the rows from the query result set and puts them into
a HTML table row */

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
 echo("<tr><td>" . $row["horse_name"] . "</td>");
 echo("<td>" . $row["year_foaled"] . "</td>");
 echo("<td>" . $row["trainer"] . "</td>");
 echo("<td>" . $row["owners"] . "</td>");
 echo("<td>" . $row["silks"] . "</td>");
 echo("<td><a href=\"" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?horseID=" .$row['horseID'] . "&Submit=Edit\">Edit</a></td></tr>");
}

/* closes the table */
?>
</table>
<?

/* closes connection to the MySQL server */

mysql_close ($conn);

/* Displays HTML Form */
html_form();

}

function get_data() {

/* Calls our connection function */

$conn = my_conn();

/* Defines query */

$sql = "SELECT * FROM horses WHERE (horses.horseID = " . $_REQUEST['horseID'] . ")";

/* Passes query to database */

$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
if (!$result) {
 echo("<p>Error performing query: " . mysql_error() . "</p>");
 exit();
}

/* creates our row array with an if statement to report errors */

if ($row = @mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

/* prints out the horse name */

print "<h4>$row[horse_name]</h4>";

/* prints out our HTML form '\"' */

print "<form name=\"horseupdate\" method=\"post\" action=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]\">";

/* prints out our HTML table and fields 'escaping' any double quotes '\"' */

print "<table width=\"600\">

<tr>
<td width=\"150\"><strong>Horse Name</strong></td>
<td width=\"350\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"horse_name\" value=\"$row[horse_name]\"></td>
<td rowspan=\"5\" valign=\"top\">
<input type=\"submit\" name=\"Submit\" value=\"Update\">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width=\"150\"><strong>Year Foaled</strong></td> 
<td width=\"350\"><input type=\"text\" size =\"4\" name=\"year_foaled\" value=\"$row[year_foaled]\"></td> 
</tr>  

<tr>
<td width=\"150\"><strong>Trainer</strong></td> 
<td width=\"350\"><input type=\"text\" size =\"40\" name=\"trainer\" value=\"$row[trainer]\"></td> 
</tr>

<tr>
<td width=\"150\"><strong>Owners</strong></td> 
<td width=\"350\"><input type=\"text\" size =\"40\" name=\"owners\" value=\"$row[owners]\"></td> 
</tr>

<tr>
<td width=\"150\"><strong>Silks</strong></td> 
<td width=\"350\"><input type=\"text\" size =\"40\" name=\"silks\" value=\"$row[silks]\"></td> 
</tr>

</table>
</form>";

} else {
 echo("There has been an error" . mysql_error());
}

/* closes connection */

mysql_close ($conn);

}

function update_horse() {

/* Calls our connection function */

$conn = my_conn();

/* Defines query */

$sql_update = "UPDATE horses SET ";
$sql_update .= "horses.year_foaled = '" . $_REQUEST['year_foaled'] . "', ";
$sql_update .= "horses.trainer = '" . $_REQUEST['trainer'] . "', ";
$sql_update .= "horses.owners = '" . $_REQUEST['owners'] . "', ";
$sql_update .= "horses.silks = '" . $_REQUEST['silks'] . "', ";
$sql_update .= "WHERE (horses.horseID = " . $_REQUEST['horseID'] . ")";

/* Passes query to database */

$result = mysql_query($sql_update, $conn);
if (!$result) {
 echo("<p>Error performing query: " . mysql_error() . "</p>");
 exit();
}

/* Prints success message */

print "<p> Successfully Updated</p>";

/* closes connection */

mysql_close ($conn);

/* Calls get_data() function */

getdata();

}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello little Bobby Tables: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Just a quick note; never post any security credentials (i.e. username and password for your database).

Comment: in reference to the comment above - the query you run is susceptible to sql injection. You should sanitize the input before putting it in a query - look at mysql_escape_string http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php

Comment: Better to use parameterized SQL calls than escapes, they are easier to manage.

Answer (score 2):

Your update form doesn't have an  element with name = "horseID", which your update function is trying to use to specify which horse to update. You've got a hidden name field there though!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `horseID` variable hasn't been set in the form that is posting to the update script, you could see this easily if you outputted your SQL query. You really need to look also at sanitising your variables before using them in a query using [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) and using `$_GET` or `$_POST` over `$_REQUEST`. If this is based on a tutorial - you really should use a different one as there is so much bad practice in your code that its actually very scary

Comment: Thanks for your answer - your comment about the tutorial being no good has me wondering if you can recommend anything online for me to work with?  Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do when debugging this kind of trouble: find out exactly what SQL statement you are trying to execute. Put an `echo $sql_update` before you actually execute it and make sure it is doing what you want. Then you can start tracking down where the problem is.

The 'Bobby Tables' comment is someone trying to tell you that you also need to escape user input. Use `mysql_real_escape_string` to ensure that user input cannot be used to attack your website.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, but this one definitely got me over the line.  Echoing the sql update showed me I had an extra comma which was breaking the update.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

`<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"horse_name\" value=\"$row[horse_name]\">`

with

`<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"horseID\" value=\"$row[horseID]\">`

It doesn't look like you need horse name anywhere in your update.